# OpenLayers view.getResolution() syntax error

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo, visual-studio

I'm trying OpenLayers 3 with .net and the sample has this code for getting feature info from a WMS.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
  var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
  if (url) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
        '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
  }
});
```

This line give me sintaxis error.

```
var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
```

But several sites have the same sample code.

I can see looks like a comment line.

So how i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment is an annotation for the Closure Compiler. So if you don't compile your application code with the Closure Compiler then you don't need that comment at all. So you can safely remove the comment (and the brackets around the right-value):

```js
var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
```

Note that you will find such annotations in the [official ol3 examples](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/). This is because, as part of ol3's continuous integration process, the ol3 examples are verified (type-checked) using Closure Compiler. But again, these type expressions are not necessary if you do compile your application code using the Closure Compiler.